# Asp.Net: Is it possible filtering a list in a content page by a value set in its master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible filtering a list in a content page by a value set in its master page? I mean when a user clicks on a link button in master page a variable is set and then based on the value that variable, when loading a content page, a list in it is filtered?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely.  The only trick is to cast `Page.Master` to the type of master page that you're using.

Here's a quick example I whipped up:

**MasterPage.master**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnToggleEvensOnly" Text="Toggle Even Number Filtering" OnClick="btnToggleEvensOnly_Click" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**MasterPage.master.cs**

```
public bool IsFiltered
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["isFiltered"] == null ? false : (bool) ViewState["isFiltered"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["isFiltered"] = value;
    }
}

protected void btnToggleEvensOnly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsFiltered = !IsFiltered;
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptList">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td><%# Eval("i") %></td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new MyItem { i = i });
    }

    var query = items.AsEnumerable();
    if (((MasterPage)Master).IsFiltered)
    {
        query = query.Where(mi => mi.i % 2 == 0);
    }

    rptList.DataSource = query;
    rptList.DataBind();

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}

public class MyItem
{
    public int i { get; set; }
}
```